# facebook-androidk-sdk 3.0.1 as library project in maven android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook, android-maven-plugin

I'm using maven to manage my dependency, how can i add the facebook-androidk-sdk 3.0.1 as library project in pom.

Where i can get the latest code for facebook sdk 3.0.1

I treed to build the apk, but I'm gettting following error please advice how to fix this issue

```
 'drawable' with value '@drawable/com_facebook_picker_list_selector_background_transition'
```

Samith

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook SDK is a normal Android library, in order to use it with Maven you need to do the following:

1. Create the apklib
2. Install the apklib in your local or remote repository
3. Add the apklib dependency to your project pom.xml

Take a look at the documentation for commands examples:
https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib

You can obtain the Facebook SDK here: https://developers.facebook.com/android/downloads/

Comment: thanks, is this git project is same https://github.com/Bizzby/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: Actually I have no idea. But the procedure to create the apk would be the same.